# I want to transfer files as well as folders which is in same structure in blob storage to sharepoint document library

Tags: azure, sharepoint, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

The files will get updated in blob storage everyday so I want in incremental method which transfer only new files and create folder in SharePoint if it is not exists. For example mycontainer/folder/20210101/test.csv , mycontainer/folder/20210102/test.csv the csv files may be single file or multiple files. I have created workflow in logic app but somehow I got stuck here I am attaching my screenshot of my workflow.
Image screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the overall flow
[image]

This is how I achieved your requirement

I first built a folder where files will be added on a daily basis, and then I used compose connector to retrieve the 'LastModifiedDate' from it.

Here is the Compose Connector Expression that I used [Compose]

```
substring(join(split(triggerBody()?['LastModified'],'-'),''),0,8)
```

[image]

Later I have created another folder with it and added the file to that folder. Then I used compose connector in order to get the path

Here is the Path Compose Connector [Compose2]

```
substring(body('Create_blob_(V2)')?['Path'],0,lastIndexOf(body('Create_blob_(V2)')?['Path'],'/'))
```

[image]

Lastly, I have used a SharePoint connector and created a folder using the above path where in the next step I created a file same as the blob structure.

[image]

Here are the screenshots from my storage account and SharePoint
**`Storage Account`**

[image]

---

**`Sharepoint`**

[image]

### Update

I noticed that the blob was erased when I added the Delete blob connector at the end with blob as the 'List of files path.' As a result, this may meet the criteria.

[image]

Comment: I DONT WANT TO CREATE AGAIN IN BLOB IT IS TAKING HUGE SPACE. IS THERE ANY ALTERNATE??

Comment: @Parker Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: How to trigger subfolder should we use httpv request

Comment: Can I know which subfolder are you talking about as we have subfolders for blob and sharepoint?

Comment: blob subfolders for example i am adding files in mycontainer/new/20211021/test.csv , mycontainer/new/20211022/test1.csv and so on in that so in new folder there are folders with date name and inside that folder i add files so, i want to trigger in blob

Comment: Add a `When a blob is added or modified` trigger wherever you wanted in the flow and give container path to mycontainer/new/20211021 . Here is the example https://i.imgur.com/ufuxIet.png

Comment: you showed for one sub-folder, how to trigger multiple subfolders

Comment: You are not getting my point if the folder structure in blob is mycontainer/new/folder1/test.csv 
mycontainer/new/folder1/test1.csv 
mycontainer/new/folder2/test2,csv
mycontainer/new/folder2/test3.csv so folder1 has 2 csv files and folder2 has 2 csv files then how will you create folder1 and folder2 in sharepoint you have showed as lastmodified in compose but i want folder1 and folder 2 in sharepoint and inside that i want csv files.

Comment: As your primary question was about creating the folder with the name that it is getting added, I have provided the solution for the same by having the last modified date which will take only the date, and will create a new folder with the same. and yes, all the newly added files will be added to respective folders even when we are adding them individually. The whole flow creates one single folder for that particular date and adds every other file into that folder. The same thing happens in blob and sharepoint as well.

Comment: Ok.. But what is the solution if I want subfolders in blob to create in SharePoint I don't want to create last modified I have show you example in date format what if it runs logic app tomorrow, it will show tomorrow date instead of yesterday's date.. So how to give folder name as it is in blob

Comment: If this isn't automation then I guess we can do only do it manually

Comment: Can you remove the create blob action could do u the same?

Comment: How did you even write that compose 2 formula. Can you explain me that